# Post request is not working but working fine in Browser?

Tags: ios, json, http-post

This is my code which uses POST request to retrieve data but i am not able to get the desired results. There is no problem in url because it is showing JSON output on browser.

```
NSString *urlString = @"my url string";                      
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];          
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];       
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email_string\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n",allIOSContactsEmailAddresses] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (data!=nil)
    {
        NSArray* array=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"array=%@",array);
    }        
}];
```

it is showing array=(null) in console..

Comment: Check whether there are any spaces or special characters in the URL

Comment: there is no spaces or special character in the url and i am doing string encoding as well

Comment: What are you getting in response? Are you getting an error? Please also post the code that sends the request.

Comment: this code is not able to connect to the php..

Comment: so there must be some error in writing the above code for POST request, but i am not able to find that..

Comment: In the completionHandler block, if `data` is nil, then check the `error` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your multipart message body is not properly setup.

After the last part (you have only one) there needs to be a "close-boundary-delimiter". So, before you set the body for the request, you need to append the delimiter:

```
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Strictly, there's no need to close the "close-boundary-delimiter" with a CRLF ("\r\n").

There is no need to prepend the actual body value (*allIOSContactsEmailAddresses*) with a CRLF (you did not). This CRLF would count as body content. Actually, this can confuse the consumer.

Contrary, for text bodies, a *closing* CRLF *may* sometimes needed (depends on the server).

Note when adding a header, it must be closed with a CRLF (as you did). In order to close the header area a closing CRLF is required. Regarding this, your message is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to use your code, and it succeeded without any problem.

Therefore your problem is in the server you send the request to, or in your NSURLConnection delegate methods which are not implemented properly.

You should also post the sending code (NSURLConnection usage).